# How to call multiple subs with a BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, vb.net-2010

I have not yet used BackgroundWorker but believe I need to use these in my code.

My app does a lot of database work, running many SQL queries in sequence. My problem appears typical, that the main form becomes unresponsive.

I want to be able to display progress using a progressbar and a toolstripstatuslabel. I am doing this already, but without the BackgroundWorker.

My code is - unsurprisingly - divided into a several subs, which are called in sequence by the main form.

All the examples I have seen include just simple BackgroundWorker DoWork events. What is the correct way to deal with calling other code? Just call the modules as usual in the DoWork event? I do understand these must contain no user interface code.

Am using VB.Net 2010

Thanks!

Comment: "Just call the modules as usual in the DoWork event?" - You got it.  Give it a go and if you have problem then ask how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Rene147, I tried it and it worked.

Comment: @Rene147 please enter this as an answer, so I can accept it and you get your points.